# Curl not working on wamp 2.2e

Tags: php, wamp

After installing the wamp 2.2e , I have uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini file at  `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini` and restarted my wamp.

Still curl is not working,it is not visible using *phpinfo*. I am using windows 7 32 bit operating system.php version on wamp is 5.3.13

I am also getting following error in *apache_error.log* file

```
    Unable to load dynamic library 'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_curl.dll' - 
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Which php.ini? There are two

Comment: Pl check php_curl extension in PHP option in WAMP

Comment: @Ananad I already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re installation and renaming previously existing wamp installation directory worked for me.
I was having a lower version of wamp already installed on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have modified the wrong `php.ini`.  Run the below code, get the location and modify it there

```
<?php
echo $inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
```

and ofcourse.. save it and restart your webserver !

Comment: Since you are on a 32-bit, Check this link out. https://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php#85098

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace library which is shipped with Wamp. It does not work for some reason on win7 x64, use this instead (ofc use version which is correct for your installation):

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-window

Comment: but I am using a 32 bit system.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your post. Then I suggest to check if you are changing correct php.ini

It is stated in the phpinfo() which php.ini is loaded. Then check if proper dll exists in extensions directory.

Answer (score 0):

Curl requires these dll's

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

which are in the \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z folder but as you are running it under apache you have to copy them to the \wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z folder

Try that.